# How do we get the data by comparing two columns of the same table in blade page

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table named `performance` which consist of the fields `user_id`, `assigned_by` and `goal_name`. `user_id` stores the value of different users & `assigned_by` stores the value of the `user_id` who assigned the particular goal.

I have to count all those values in which `user_id` are same as `assigned_by`. How can i do that?

This is my table:

```
       | User_id | goal_name     | assigned_by |
        _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
       |    1     | walk daily   |    1        |
       |    2     | sleep better |    9        |
       |    1     | drink water  |    5        |
       |    1     | eat healthy  |    1        |
       - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

This is the code I use for the count:

```php
$dam = \App\performance::where('User_id','=','assigned_by')->count();
dd($dam);
```

But it will return 0. But it has to return 2 because two records have the same `user_id` & `assigned_by` value. Please help.

Comment: How does a function design to count return a Boolean of false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to laravel docs:

> The whereColumn method may be used to verify that two columns are equal:
>
> ```php
> $users = DB::table('users')
>                ->whereColumn('first_name', 'last_name')
>                ->get();
> ```

To solve your issue:

```php
$dam = DB::table('performance')->whereColumn('user_id', 'assigned_by')->count();
```

or

```php
$dam = \App\Performance::whereColumn('user_id', 'assigned_by')->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `whereColumn` like this:

```
$dam = \App\performance::whereColumn('User_id','assigned_by')->count();
```

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses). Under "whereColumn / orWhereColumn" section.